# Matching more than one instance of same parameter with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm having some problem with a rewrite rule. I have a website that accepts as parameter a paging options, as parameter in any position

```
index.php?page=2
index.php?other_parameter=other_value&page=2&another_paramenter=another_value
```

Now problem is that some crawlers use to append all the parameters they can see on the page, so they try

```
index.php?page=2&page=3&page=4
index.php?other_parameter=other_value&page=2&page=3&page=4&another_paramenter=another_value
```

I'd like to block these second attempts, so basically block any call that has in the query parameters more than one instance of page=NN, possibly redirecting them to homepage.

I'm using https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/ to test some regexp to match this, but I just can't seem to find a way to block any url with multiple page= parameters.

Any hint how you would do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule to block such query strings:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(page=)\d+(?=&(?:.*&)?\1) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bzcCs/1)

Regex pattern in this condition matches `page=<number>` if that is followed by another instance of the `page=` anywhere in the query string. If match is successful that request is denied (403).

Comment: Thank you @anubhava this indeed worked perfectly. Very smart!

Comment: Actually I slightly modified it as first parameter could start with a ? or with a & so I modified it into: `(?:^|/?|&)(page=)\d+(?=&(?:.*&)?\1)`

Comment: `?` is never part of the `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Ah, weirdly enough it works now though. So how could I do it so that it catches the query string that starts with `?` or with `&` ?

Comment: Query string is something that comes after `?` only. If `?` is missing then whole thing becomes `REQUEST_URI`.